# "Linear algebraic" proof of Frobenius normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Theorem: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, there exists a basis such that $V$ can be represented by the direct sum of some $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic subspace of $V$.

I want to proof this theorem in an "linear algebraic" way, but my proof is stuck somewhere and can't get the final result.

I proof this theorem by induction on dimension of $V$.

1. When $d=1$, the theorem is correct obviously.
2. Suppose the throrem is correct when $d\le n-1$. When $d=n$, choose any $v\in V,v\ne 0$, then we can generate $v$ to be a $\mathcal{A}$ cyclic subspace(denote by $U$). Note that U is $\mathcal{A}$ invariant, we can consider the quotient space $V/U$ which dimension is less than $n$.

But by induction, we can only know that under this basis, $\mathcal{A}$ can be represented by an **upper triangular matrix**, not a diagonal matrix. I don't know what conditions I overlooked.

In summary, I want a "linear algebraic" proof of this theorem and the **uniqueness** of Frobenius normal form.

Thanks.

Comment: "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze has a linear algebraic proof of this result

Comment: It is not true that the $\mathcal A$-cyclic subspace generated by an arbitrary non-zero vector can be used as a term in the cyclic decomposition of $\mathcal A$. As a counterexample, let $\mathcal A$ be the operator associated with the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$
$\mathcal A$ is the zero operator over the 1-dimensional $\mathcal A$-cyclic subspace $(1,0)$. However, there is no matrix $M$ for which $A$ is similar to
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & B}.
$$
An important piece here is that each part of the decomposition must be "$\mathcal A$-admissible".

Comment: Thanks a lot  :）